# How to replace spaces with dashes of folder names (in bulk)

Tags: windows, batch-file, renaming

How to replace spaces with dashes of several thousand folders in bulk in Windows server 2008?.

Currently:

My folder

All folders need to become:

My-folder

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works here.

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /D /R %%i IN (*) DO (
    SET "n=%%~nxi"
    REN "%%i" "!n: =-!"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /D /R %%i IN (*.*) DO (
    SET "n=%%~nxi"
    SET n=!n: =-!
    IF NOT "!n!" == "%%~nxi" ECHO MOVE "%%~i" "%%~dpi!n!"
)
```

Check results and if everything looks OK, remove `ECHO` before `MOVE`.

EDIT: Interactive version:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET k=
FOR /D /R %%i IN (*.*) DO (
    SET "n=%%~nxi"
    SET n=!n: =-!
    IF NOT "!n!" == "%%~nxi" (
        ECHO "%%~i" =^> "!n!"
        IF /I NOT "!k!"=="A" SET /P k=[Y]es/[N]o/[A]ll]/[C]ancel?
        IF /I "!k!"=="C" GOTO :END
        IF /I "!k!"=="Y" MOVE "%%~i" "%%~dpi!n!"
        IF /I "!k!"=="A" MOVE "%%~i" "%%~dpi!n!"
    )
)
:END
PAUSE
```

Test this batch. It will ask before any rename (unless you enter <kbd>A</kbd>), so you can preview command and check result.

Comment: nothing happened i saved it in bat but still the folders have spaces

Comment: You're supposed to check bat output - Then, if all ok, remove ECHO before MOVE to make it work. As already explained in answer.

Comment: here is the file i created using the code you gave me is doesn'

Comment: so sorry it doesn't do anything at all so could you please take a look at it and tell what should i do and what i'm doing wrong   https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/125658459/renamedash.bat

Comment: Ok, I tested in my machine and it worked fine. I added an interactive version to answer, check it.